# How to show values from database in adminform

Tags: magento-1.9, database, adminform

I have created a custom module to save fields in database now want to get all the fields value into the form so they will be shown in admin:

Here is my adminform:

```
<?php

  class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Form extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
      {
/**
 * Preparing form
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $helper = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array('legend' => $helper->__('Select Social Icons'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'facebook',
        'label' => $helper->__('Facebook'),
        'value' => 'facebook.com'
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('google', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'google',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('twitter', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'twitter',
        'label' => $helper->__('Twitter'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('linkedin', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'linkedin',
        'label' => $helper->__('Linkedin'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('yelp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yelp',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yelp'),
        ));


    if (Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
```

This is the form in admin:
[image]
I want to create a view where all the form fields will be shown there database value.. is that can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php

  class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Form extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
      {
{
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                                        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                        'method' => 'post',
                                     )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Create on more file **Block/Adminhtml/ReviewMyCompany/Edit/Tab/Form.php**

```
   <?php

    class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_ReviewMyCompany_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    {
     $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
            $this->setForm($form);
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('modulename_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('proxelle')->__('Item information')));

            $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Facebook'),
                'class'     => 'required-entry',
                'required'  => true,
                'name'      => 'facebook',
            ));

}
```

I guess you missed folder structure for more Follow this http://kamleshkamble.blogspot.in/2013/02/custom-module-in-magento-with-custom.html

Comment: its giving error at this line  $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

Comment: Update your full error

Comment: it is some type of syntax error in IDE

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/dsHYYVOOn check here

Comment: change modulename into your modulename and change proxelle into your modulename